# Why can't you use cat to read a file line by line where each line has delimiters

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, cat

I have a text file that contains something like this:

```
abc 123, comma
the quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy dog
comma, comma
```

I wrote a script

```
for i in `cat file`
do
   echo $i
done
```

For some reason, the output of the script doesn't output the file line by line but breaks it off at the commas, as well as the newline.  Why is `cat` or `` for blah in `cat xyz` `` doing this and how can I make it NOT do this?  I know I can use a

```
while read line
do
   blah balh blah
done < file
```

but I want to know why `cat` or the `for var in` is doing this to further my understanding of Unix commands.  `cat`'s man page didn't help me and looking at `for` or *looping* in the bash manual didn't yield any answers (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is not in `cat`, nor in the `for` loop per se; it is in the use of back quotes.  When you write either:

```
for i in `cat file`
```

or (better):

```
for i in $(cat file)
```

or (in `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash`¹):

```
for i in $(<file)
```

the shell executes the command and captures the output as a string, removes trailing newline characters (and all NULs with bash) separating the words at the characters in `$IFS` and (except in zsh) performs *globbing* aka *filename generation* aka *pathname expansion* on the resulting words.  If you want lines input to `$i`, you either have to fiddle with `IFS` or use the `while` loop.  The `while` loop is better if there's any danger that the files processed will be large; it doesn't have to read the whole file into memory all at once, and doesn't perform globbing and doesn't skip empty lines unlike the versions using `$(...)`.

```
IFS='
'
set -o noglob # disable globbing
for i in $(<file)
do printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

The quotes around the `"$i"` are generally a good idea.  In this context, with the modified `$IFS`, and globbing disabled, it actually isn't critical, but good habits are good habits even so. `printf` is better than `echo`, as `echo` would output nothing or an empty line for input lines containing `-n`, `-nene`, `-eee` or depending on the `echo` implementation and/or environment mangle backslashes.   That matters in the following script:

```
old="$IFS"
IFS='
'
set -o noglob
for i in $(<file)
do
   (
   IFS="$old"
   set +o noglob
   printf '%s\n' "$i"
   )
done
```

when the data file contains tabulations or multiple spaces (both of which are in the default value of `$IFS`) or wildcards or leading trailing whitespace

```
$ cat file
abc                  123
  foo
-Enee
/e* /b*
$
```

Output:

```
$ sh bq.sh
abc                  123
  foo
-Enee
/e* /b*
$
```

With `echo` and without the double quotes:

```
$ cat bq.sh
old="$IFS"
IFS='
'
set -o noglob
for i in $(<file)
do
   (
   IFS="$old"
   set +o noglob
   echo $i
   )
done
$ sh bq.sh
abc 123
foo
/etc /bin /boot
$
```

For the `while read` loop, the syntax should be:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
   printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < file
```

- without `-r`, `read` would mangle backslashes
- without `IFS=`, `read` would remove leading and trailing space and tabs (assuming the default value of `$IFS`).
- `printf` should be used instead of `echo`, and `$line` quoted for the same reasons as above.

---

<sup>¹ Though in bash it's much less of an optimisation as bash still forks a child process to perform the expansion.</sup>

Comment: thx for your help and reply. I'm a little confused here with bash/*nix. I didn't change IFS. It's set as a newline by default. I checked it with echo "IFS = $IFS word test" and the string "word test" got printed to the following line so we know it's \n by default. In any case, using the default IFS, it breaks my line at the comma even though IFS=\n. When I do as you suggested above, by setting the IFS explicitly to \n, then it prints my whole line without breaking over the comma. Any idea why it works when it's explicitly set as \n and not work when by default IFS is already \n? Thanks again.

Comment: The default value of IFS is (using a piece of `bash`-speak) `$' \t\n'`; that is, it consists of blank, tab, newline.  This probably alters your analysis.  When you say 'breaks at the comma', you mean it breaks at the space after the comma, I believe, which is consistent with IFS containing blank (and tab and newline).

Answer (score 7):

```
cat filename | while read i
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: most sane idea!

Comment:  UUOC, missing `IFS=` and `-r` for `read`, missing quotes around `$i`, `echo` instead of `printf`. That cumulates every possible bad practice that one could think of here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `IFS` variable to specific you want a newline as the field separator:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat file`
do
   echo $i
done
```

Comment: Unsafe -- you've prevented string-splitting, but you haven't prevented glob expansion. If a line contains `*`, that will be expanded to a list of names in the current directory during the echo.

Answer (score 3):

the for loop coupled with a change of the internal field separator(IFS) will read file as intended

for an input

```
abc 123, comma
the quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy dog
comma, comma
```

For loop coupled with an IFS change

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat file`
do
        echo $i
done
IFS=$old_IFS
```

results in

```
abc 123, comma
the quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy dog
comma, comma
```

Comment: Simply use `IFS= read -r line` to preserve all whitespace in the line.

Comment: The only reason the spacing is 'lost' with the `while` loop is because you used `echo $line` rather than `echo "$line"`.  If spacing is important, enclose the variable reference in double quotes.

Comment: As chepner says, this should be `read -r` to avoid unintended side effects (evaluating backslash escape sequences).

Answer (score 2):

IFS - Internal field separator can be set to get what you want.

To read a whole line at once, use:
IFS=""

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the new `IFS` setting from altering your shell, you don't need to do any of the other mentioned stuff...

Use a subshell by putting the command in parentheses (I also prefer setting the IFS by using an escape sequence; this makes it easier to read what is done):

```bash
(IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat file); do echo $i; done)
```

The semicolons replace otherwise necessary line breaks, the parentheses each open a subshell, the `$(...)` syntax replaces the subshell invocation with its output to stdout and the `$` before the single quotes leads to escape sequence interpretation inside the single quotes (does not work for double quotes and is a bashism, i.e. won't work with any other POSIX shell).

Alternatively, you could

```bash
(IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat file); do
    echo $i
done)
```

or even put the `do` or the parentheses on their own lines if that's what you want.