# trying to read every line in file, output always 'cat $file'

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to display every line of a file in the terminal but the output is always:

> cat $file

this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="users.csv"
IFS=''
echo "bobama, Barack Obama" > $file
echo "gbush, George Bush" >> $file
for line in `cat $file`;
do
        echo $line;
done
```

Comment: why dont you just write `cat $file` instead of looping it over it?

Comment: Even though this is not the way to loop through the content of a file, it does work to me. See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the approach recommended by 9 out of 10 dentists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing `'cat $file'` with `$(cat $file)`.

You can find a better explanation here:
[Why can't you use cat to read a file line by line where each line has delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099860/why-cant-you-use-cat-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-where-each-line-has-delimiters)

Comment: Your question says `\`cat $file\`` Your answer says error was due to `'cat $file'`. Both are different.